# Updating git orphan branch for public release of previously proprietary software

Tags: git, github, open-source

I am open sourcing a project that previously had proprietary code, so I do not want to publish its entire history. I used these commands to create an orphan branch:

```
git checkout -b opensource-prep
... changed a bunch of code, add open source license, etc.
git commit -m "Prep for open source"
git checkout --orphan opensource opensource-prep
git commit -m "Open source release"
```

Since then, I have committed more changes to master and merged into opensource-prep. How do I release the new code into the opensource branch without exposing the entire history? I also would like to ensure that it's done properly so that people who may have forked opensource can safely pull the newest changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's automated mechanisms will fail, because they will be unable to find a common ancestor: 
Technically speaking, your two branches do not share any common commits, because the information on the parents is part of a commit. So a plain merge or rebase won't help here.

IMHO, the cleanest way to publish your new changes is to create a new orphaned branch and merge the old state of the *opensource* branch with the *ours* strategy: Users will see that they're lacking your private history, but still be able to pull from your repository, because it is recorded that the new release supersedes the old one.

Another option is to rebase with `upsteam` set to the commit in the *opensource-prep* tree that you used for the last commit to the *opensource* branch (I call that `<commit>` below), `branch` set to *opensource-prep*, and `onto` to *opensource*. Mind that this will override the *opensource-prep* branch, so you'll want to work with a copy, i.e.

```
git checkout -b opensource-new opensource-prep
git rebase [-i] <commit> opensource-new --onto opensource
git branch -M opensource-new opensource
```

Comment: The new orphan branch method does seem to be the cleanest, and I consider coalescing all of my changes into one commit to be a bonus. However, merging leaves a pointer to the first commit on the temporary orphan branch, and that commit is huge. Maybe cherry-pick would work better?

Comment: It's not any larger than it has to be: Git always stores the whole tree in each commit; optimization in terms of incremental storage happens on another abstraction level. i.e. files that are unchanged between the old opensource branch and the new orphaned version will still only be stored once. Using cherry(-pick), you'll have to supply the `<limit>` parameter the same way I've used `<commit>` in the above example. AFAIK this will essentially give you the same result the rebase would.